# Howto customize TableCell/TableColumn content according to its row element in TableView (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecell, tablecolumn

[image]

### Issue

I have a `TableColumn<User, String> colPassword` which currently **only** display existing passwords (String) as masked for each entry (row).

### Needs

I need your help, so that each `TableCell` only shows the ***masked*** password if the user for the respective row: **user.isManager == true**, otherwise the password should be ***unmasked***.

### My current approach

I will provide only the crucial parts to ease the understanding.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private boolean deleted = false;
    private final BooleanProperty manager = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private final StringProperty password = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    public User() {
    }

    public boolean isManager() {
        return manager.get();
    }

    public void setManager(boolean value) {
        manager.set(value);
    }

    public BooleanProperty managerProperty() {
        return manager;
    }
```

UserController for GUI

```
public class UsersController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<User> tblUsers;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> colPassword;

    private void initTableColumns() {
        colPassword.setCellValueFactory(cellData
                    -> cellData.getValue().passwordProperty()
        );
        colPassword.setCellFactory((TableColumn<User, String> param) -> {
            return new PasswordFieldCell();
        });
    }
```

here is the custom TabelCell

```
public class PasswordFieldCell extends TableCell<User, String> {

    private final Label lbl;

    public PasswordFieldCell() {
        lbl = new Label();
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.setGraphic(null);
    }

    private String generatePasswordString(int len) {
        String dots = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            dots += "*";
        }

        return dots;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            lbl.setText(generatePasswordString(item.length()));
            setGraphic(lbl);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution

With help of [VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831987/vgr) I was able to come up with this solution in PasswordFieldCell.

```
public class PasswordFieldCell extends TableCell<User, String> {

    private final Label lbl;

    public PasswordFieldCell() {
        lbl = new Label();
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        this.setGraphic(null);
    }

    private String generatePasswordString(int len) {
        String dots = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            dots += "*";
        }

        return dots;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            int row = getIndex();
            User user = getTableView().getItems().get(row);

            if (user.isManager()) { // mask password
                lbl.setText(generatePasswordString(item.length()));
            } else { // unmask password
                lbl.setText(item);
            }

            setGraphic(lbl);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PasswordFieldCell class inherits a lot of useful methods from [TableCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html).

In particular, you inherit a getTableView() method, and a getIndex() method which returns the row of the current cell.  Those are all you need to look up the cell’s row value in your `updateItem` method:

```
int row = getIndex();
User user = getTableView().getItems().get(row);
```

Comment: thanks you for your efforts! You saved my day! I updated my entry to incorporate your answer!